# Unable to convert Jupyter Notebooks into python scripts Jupyter command `jupyter-nbconvert` not found

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am using VS studio and every time I want to convert my Jupyter notebook to a python script it gives me this error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 207, in run_module
   return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
   _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
 File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
   exec(code, run_globals)
 File "C:\Users\'myname'\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter.py", line 4, in <module>
   main()
 File "C:\Users\'myname'\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 247, in main
   command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
 File "C:\Users\'myname'\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 133, in _jupyter_abspath
   raise Exception(
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-nbconvert` not found
```

How can I fix this?